# text-to-speech using VB.NET 2008

Tags: .net, vb.net, text-to-speech

text-to-speech for English language using Visual Basic 2008

```
Dim speech As Object = CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice") 
speech.speak(TextBox1.Text)
```

My question, how this can be used for other languages(Spoken Languages!!!)?
thanks

Comment: That code doesn't compile. And what other languages are you talking about? Spoken languages? Programming languages?

Answer (score 6):

The SAPI interface got a nice wrapper in .NET 3.0, System.Speech.Synthesis namespace.  Usable in any .NET compatible language.  Use Project > Add Reference and select System.Speech.  Write code similar to :

```
 Imports System.Speech.Synthesis
 ...
    Dim synth = New SpeechSynthesizer
    synth.Speak("Works in any .NET language")
```

Answer (score 1):

The Sapi interface is a COM-interface. 
You can use this with most languages (on windows) which support COM, e.g. PHP, C, VBA, ...

...but if you mean real-world languages, you have to install additional "voices"

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_text-to-speech_voices
- http://www.bytecool.com/voices.htm